# AWS CLI get status of deployment after deploying to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

The last line of my deployment task using the AWS CLI is

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name DevApi --environment-name Dev --version-label v2
```

How can I check that the deployment of v2 was successful? At the moment I have another browser window open `console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/` and check there. But there has to be a better way to automate it as part of my deployment by adding another step (cli command?) so I only need to check the deployment output?

EDIT: I should also mention I am running a Windows Elastic Beanstalk instance.

Answer (score 3):

One way I can think of is to check the ***EBS Health Reports***.

If you are using *Basic Monitoring*, use the below cli:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --application-name DevApi  --environment-name Dev --query 'Environments[*].{Status: Status,Health: Health} --output json'
```

*`Sample output:`*

```
[
    {
        "Status": "Ready",
        "Health": "Green"
    }
]
```

For more info about each indicator, read [*Basic Health Reporting*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html#using-features.healthstatus.colors).

If you are using *Enhanced Monitoring* (for extra cost), then there is an additional parameter available which makes it much more clear.

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --application-name DevApi  --environment-name Dev --query 'Environments[*].{Status: Status,Health: Health,HealthStatus: HealthStatus} --output json'
```

*`Sample Output:`*

```
[
    {
        "Status": "Ready",
        "HealthStatus": "Ok",
        "Health": "Green"
    }
]
```

Once the above status is reached, you can conclude the deployment is complete and is healthy. 
If the *HealthStatus* is `Info` and *Health* is `Green`, It indicates An operation is in progress on an instance (or) on several instances in an environment. **Example:** *A new application version is being deployed to running instances.*

For more info about each health indicator, do read [*Enhanced Health reporting*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-status.html).